# How could I evaluate multiple lines for loop in a Java assert statement?

Tags: java, assert

I am looking to sum the values of an array and make a quick calculation using the result of that sum, then use the result of that calculation to compare to an already existing number so the comparison forms the condition of the assert. Can I place the for loop and calculations next to the assert keyword, or must I create a function separately that contains the for loop call it from the assert statement?

Comment: Share you actual code please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`assert` takes an expression; a `for` loop is a statement.  You could sum the array in an expression using a streams operation:

```
assert Arrays.stream(array).sum() == expectedSum;
```

or, as you suggested, call out to a function that does something similar.

Comment: Perhaps, it’s time to rethink Java’s distinction between expressions and statements. After all, we can circumvent this distinction, e.g. since Java 8: `assert ((Predicate<int[]>)a -> { 
 int sum = 0;  for(int i: a) sum += i;  return sum == expectedSum;  }).test(array);`. Even better, because it truly consists of expressions containing statements without class-like constructs, is JDK 14: `assert switch(0) { default -> { int sum = 0; for(int i: array) sum += i; yield sum == expectedSum; } };`. I see no reason why this shouldn’t be possible with a plain block without the dummy `switch` statement